# how to run 2 functions simoultaneously in Python3

Tags: python

I have been searching here how to do it, but none of the examples I have seen work for me, I have tried with thread, process from multiprocessing, with futures from concurrent...

I have this basic silly test:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

counter = 0


def func1():
    global counter
    print('start func1')
    while counter < 10:
        print("func1")
        counter += 1
    print('end func1')


def func2():
    global counter
    print('start func2')
    while counter < 10:
        print("func2")
        counter += 1
    print('end func2')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=func1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=func2)
    p2.start()
```

but this is the output I am getting:

```
start func1
func1
func1
func1
func1
func1
func1
func1
func1
func1
func1
end func1
start func2
func2
func2
func2
func2
func2
func2
func2
func2
func2
func2
end func2
```

So one function starts when the other finishes, ideally it would be start func1-start func2-func1-func2... What am I missing?

Comment: Your functions take almost no time to complete, so it happened that one of them finished before the other one even started.  Make them take more time (by adding a `time.sleep()` inside their loops, for example), and you should see their outputs interleaved.

Comment: With a fast processor, your first process will be done executing by the time your second process finishes spinning up.

Comment: @jasonharper that is true it worked now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a module called `threading`:

```
import threading
import time

def c():
   runtime = str(int(time.time())
   print("Function a is running at time: " + runtime + " seconds.")

def d():
   runtime = str(int(time.time()))
   print("Function b is running at time: " + str(int(time.time())) + " seconds.")

threading.Thread(target=c).start()

threading.Thread(target=d).start()
```

This should print the same exact run time for both functions. This allows you to connect two functions under a single thread and run them simultaneously.

Comment: ok this works fine, but when I try to use it in my real case it does not work, actually it does not even ever call the functions,. I am using threading inside the main function which as far as I understand should not be a problem, right?

Comment: Yes, that isn’t the problem. Make sure you make the correct imports because otherwise that might be a problem.